# How to create a pandas dataframe from csv where one column contains nested dictionary?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a CSV file and in one column there is a nested dictionary with the values of classification report, in a format like this one:

```
{'A': {'precision': 0.0, 'recall': 0.0, 'f1-score': 0.0, 'support': 60},

'B': {'precision': 0.42, 'recall': 0.09, 'f1-score': 0.14, 'support': 150},

'micro avg': {'precision': 0.31, 'recall': 0.31, 'f1-score': 0.31, 'support': 1710},

'macro avg': {'precision': 0.13, 'recall': 0.08, 'f1-score': 0.071, 'support': 1710},

'weighted avg': {'precision': 0.29, 'recall': 0.31, 'f1-score': 0.26, 'support': 1710}}
```

I would like to get **key_value1_level** as a **column** in a data frame. So, is it possible to get the following result?

```
A_precision A_recall ...weighted_avg_precision   weighted_avg_recall   weighted_avg_f1-score   weighted avg_support
0.0         0.0         0.29                     0.31                  0.26                                   1710
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize) on that dictionary:

```py
dct = {
    "A": {"precision": 0.0, "recall": 0.0, "f1-score": 0.0, "support": 60},
    "B": {"precision": 0.42, "recall": 0.09, "f1-score": 0.14, "support": 150},
    "micro avg": {
        "precision": 0.31,
        "recall": 0.31,
        "f1-score": 0.31,
        "support": 1710,
    },
    "macro avg": {
        "precision": 0.13,
        "recall": 0.08,
        "f1-score": 0.071,
        "support": 1710,
    },
    "weighted avg": {
        "precision": 0.29,
        "recall": 0.31,
        "f1-score": 0.26,
        "support": 1710,
    },
}

df = pd.json_normalize(dct, sep="_")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A_precision  A_recall  A_f1-score  A_support  B_precision  B_recall  B_f1-score  B_support  micro avg_precision  micro avg_recall  micro avg_f1-score  micro avg_support  macro avg_precision  macro avg_recall  macro avg_f1-score  macro avg_support  weighted avg_precision  weighted avg_recall  weighted avg_f1-score  weighted avg_support
0          0.0       0.0         0.0         60         0.42      0.09        0.14        150                 0.31              0.31                0.31               1710                 0.13              0.08               0.071               1710                    0.29                 0.31                   0.26                  1710
```

Comment: Hi, thank you @Andrej Kesely. When I try 
df = pd.json_normalize(dframe_merged['class_report'], sep="_") I get the error  
'str' object has no attribute 'values'
dframe_merged is a dataframe and 'class_report' is a column with dictionary

Comment: @mark Probably you have strings in `dframe_merged['class_report']` column. Apply on this column `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Hi, thank you @Andrej Kesely. Yes, you are right. Inside csv, around the dictionary, there are string marks " " How would you suggest changing json_normalize for that case?

Comment: Also, I'm confused with this behaviour since I created that column with option output_dict=True in the classification_report.